# Trying to add a dashed line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to add a dashed line in between my rows. Any help would be great. I just can't seem to figure it out. attached a photo as an example.
So far my code is :

```
numbers = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
for x in numbers:
  for y in letters:
     print("%s%d" % (y, x), end="\n")
     print()
```

[image]

Comment: can you pleas give us an example of how do you expect your output to be?

Comment: What do you mean? `print("----------")`?

Comment: Just attached a image for an example

Comment: in a print statement, by default `end="\n"` so you dont have to explicitly state that. Also to print a dash line, all you have to do is `print ('-'*40)` and it will print 40 `-`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you thinking something like this?

```
numbers = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

for x in numbers:
    row = '|'
    for y in letters:
        row += f' {y}{x} |'
    print('-'*len(row))
    print(row)
print('-'*len(row))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The top line is missing and there's too much padding in the first column. Also, you can just do `f' {y}{x} |'`, since conversion to str is the default.

Comment: Instead of `print ('-'*42)` use `print ('-'*len(row))`

Comment: Also switch the printing to `print ('-'*len(row))` next line `print (row)` and one more `print ('-'*len(row))` after the for loop for x is done.

Comment: @RasmusNielsen If you fix your code using the suggestions in the comments, you'll probably get some extra upvotes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're going for 2 things: separating each letter iteration with a `|`, and separating each line (and number iteration) with a line of `-`s

- If you want a vertical line after each element (your letter + number print-out) you could replace your `end=` character with the `|` symbol (and remove your extra `print()` which is adding a newline). This would look like:

```
a8 | b8 | c8 | d8 ...
```

- To add a dashed line after each `number` iterates (the outer loop in your nested for loops) you could add a `print("------")` to the end of your `y` for-loop, but within your `x` for-loop, i.e.

```
for x in numbers:
  for y in letters:
    print("%s%d" % (y, x), end="|")
  print("------")
```

Which would print a "------" at the end of each number, before incrementing, i.e.

```
a8 | b8 | c8 | d8 ...
-------
a7 | b7 | c7 | d7 ...
```

If you know beforehand how many "columns" you're iterating through (a-h) you can choose the length of this `-` line to match the length of those columns